# How to convert Erb 2 Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have write several erb template in views, how can I convert erb to haml automatically ? But not convert then hand by hand.

Comment: I don't know how many partials you have in erb, but I would argue converting them by hand is actually not a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

[`html2haml`](https://github.com/haml/html2haml) should do what you want. There's a `--erb` option that accepts ERB tags.

Comment: Also accepts -s for STDIN! Great for copying snippets off the web!

Answer (score 2):

In your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "haml-rails"
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
rake haml:erb2haml
```

If you forget how to do this, `rake -T` will show you the baked-in rake tasks; just grep for the thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

chcek the gem erb2haml. I think is right what you are looking for

more info [here](https://github.com/dhl/erb2haml)

Answer (score -1):

html2haml do it easy. And if you have too much views, probably little scripting will help you. See [that](http://snot2000.wordpress.com/2009/11/28/html2haml-for-multiple-files/)